# How to logout user if he changes his Google account password?

Tags: google-signin

I am successfuly able to login using Google but now I want to logout the user when he changes his Google account password.

I have tried the code below:

```
  OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d("TAG", "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {

            }
        });
    }
```

...but even after changing password and revoking access, I was able to silently login. I can't find anything else.

---

Can someone help me to detect if user has changed his password, so I can log him out?

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue reported for the same.
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/196

According to them it is expected behavior and you might need to explicitly call signOut or revokeAccess from your application to achieve that.